# Statutory authority to order business to close their doors

Tags: united-states, statutes, emergencies

In Maryland, Governor Hogan just ordered with "the full force of law" all restaurants, bars, movie theaters, gyms, etc. to close their doors to the public starting at 5 p.m.

What is his statutory authority to do this? I've read the MEMA code (§ 14), and read some of the health code. I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The key statutory tool is [§14-303 of Title 14](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2010/public-safety/title-14/subtitle-3/14-303/). Having previously declared a state of emergency,

> (b)  After proclaiming a state of emergency, the Governor may
>   promulgate reasonable orders, rules, or regulations that the Governor
>   considers necessary to protect life and property or calculated
>   effectively to control and terminate the public emergency in the
>   emergency area, including orders, rules, or regulations to:
>
> ...
>
> (2) designate specific zones in the emergency area in which the
>   occupancy and use of buildings and vehicles may be controlled;
>
> (3) control the movement of individuals or vehicles into, in, or from
>   the designated zones;
>
> (4) control places of amusement and places of assembly;

Comment: How is “reasonable” defined?

Comment: @Dai It's not explicitly defined, and its definition is usually up to interpretation by the courts, but it generally means ["Reasonable according to an average citizen/person"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person)